# Tig configuration open in status by default

Tags: tig

How I can start tig on status view by default?

I tried with

```
set cmdline-args = --all status
```

not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure a default view can be defined this in the settings, at least I didn't find anything related in the [tigrc documentation](https://jonas.github.io/tig/doc/tigrc.5.html). Personnally I went for the alias solution:

```
alias tigs="tig status"
```

And just launch `tig status` this way. It's not perfect but it does the job.

Comment: Is there any workaround to open tig in a split view by default on launching?